# CakePHP find condition on related models' count

Tags: cakephp

I have 3 models. Type hasMany Collector, and Collector hasAndBelongsToMany Place.

I need to get all Type which Collectors has at least one Place. So I do not need Types which Collectors has no Place.

I do not have a count field in Collector model, so I can not use counterCache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be mistaken here, but I believe the best way to do this is to utilize the Model::afterFind() method.

```
<?php
// type.php (Model)
function afterFind($results, $primary) {
    if ($primary === true) {
        foreach ($results as $key => $type) {
            foreach ($type['Collector'] as $collector) {
                // Assuming you built the associations/tables/etc. correctly and are following cake conventions.
                if (empty($collector['Place']))  {
                    unset($results[$key]);
                    continue 2;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
<?php
// types_controller.php

// Assuming you're using the containable behavior? If not
// set recursive to 2.
$this->Type->contain(array(
    'Collector' => array(
        'Place'
    )
));
$types = $this->Type->find('all');

?>
```